# Android Studio 3.5 failing to compile data bindings

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-studio-3.5

As soon as I updated to Android Studio 3.5, I started running into compilation errors. My app is using both Java and Kotlin. I have some legacy Java code using data binding. Somehow the Kotlin compiler complains about unable to find Java bindings.

I have tried the following

1. Invalidate cache/restart
2. Delete .gradle
3. Re-importing project

Comment: Try running `./gradlew assembleDebug --info` inside the Android Studio terminal to get a better idea as to where the issue lies (assuming you're on a mac).

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I just downgraded to ver 3.4 for now, was short of time to spend on it.